# Why does the multimeter detect continuity between live and neutral of my appliance?

Tags: multimeter, continuity

I was doing some random checks with my new multimeter and while doing a continuity test I heard the beeping noise when connecting the multimeter to the live and neutral ends of the plug for my 220v iron. Is this normal? Doesn't the beep indicate a short?

Comment: One would expect the iron to present a low resistance and thus your multimeter beeping. Use the resistance range to measure your iron and compare this value to what you meter beeps at. The beep function operates if the resistance is below a given value rather than a proper short circuit.

Comment: I've seem meters 'beep' with anything under 300 ohms.   Depends on what they wanna call "a short".  Internally the iron is likely just a wire  (literally) connected between LIVE and NEUTRAL.  SO you're measuring the resistance of that wire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beep does not mean short.

You must read your multimeter manual what is the resistance when it beeps and when it does not.

The iron is likely just a load which in the area of resistance where it beeps. Assuming a 880W iron, it consumes 4A at 220V, so it has 55 ohm resistance (when hot, likely less when cold).

So as it is a load, there must be continuity between live and neutral, it's just through load resistance so it is not short.

I would expect a multimeter to beep when measuring 55 ohm resistance or below.

Answer (score 2):

Your iron requires a lot of current to heat up. Since it is powered by a fixed voltage source, Ohm's law requires that the resistance of the iron be very low to get a very high current. Most multimeters' "signal" setting will beep when the resistance measured is below a certain value. You can try measuring the resistance instead of determining if there is a short between L/N.

Answer (score 0):

Diode continuity beep test buts a constant mA level current and measures voltage, which is useful for Schottky diodes vs Silicon diodes and Heater wires included.

A resistance test is more accurate on x1 or 1 Ohm resolution scale